# Is it possible to add HERE maps in ionic2 application

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2, here-api

I want to add `HERE maps` in my ionic android application, I tried searching for similar  cordova plugin for here maps but unlike google-maps here maps doesn't seem to have support for ionic2 framework, therefore I just wanted to confirm If it is even possible to do so with any workaround.

Comment: You got https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-heremaps and you got types to go with it to give you typescript typings

Comment: thanks, but I wanted to draw polyline for the route, which I suppose is not yet possible.

Comment: You could try to not install the node-heremaps package and then adding the scripts from their website to your index.html and then use it blindly. It will work there is just no typings. Point is, angular2 or ionic2 is still JavaScript in its core and you can do anything that can be done in other webpage

Comment: nope it doesn't work

Comment: I am now using intent which will open the application till there is other solution

Answer (score 0):

Special develop/support HERE JS API for Ionic, Angular, ReactJS, Vue or whatever framework was not planned.

Basically the integration of Ionic, Angular, ReactJS, Vue etc. with HERE JS API of-course is **technically possible** see please example on [Display HERE Maps within your Angular](https://developer.here.com/blog/display-here-maps-angular-web-application), once you will make an app Angular + HERE JS API then you can make [Your First Ionic App: Angular](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/your-first-app)